# Confusion about parameters in List.foldRight() in scala

Tags: scala, for-loop, pattern-matching

Why does this code work:

```
  val list = List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))

  val first = list.foldRight(List[List[(Char, Int)](List())) {
    case ((char, num), acc) =>
      (for (
        elem <- acc;
        i <- 0 to num
      ) yield (char, i) :: elem)
  }
```

where as this does not:

```
  val second = list.foldRight(List[List[(Char, Int)]](List())) {
    (elem, acc) =>
      (for (
        elem1 <- acc;
        (char, num) <- elem; // ERROR: value filter is not a member of (Char, Int)
        i <- 0 to num
      ) yield (char, i) :: elem1)
  }
```

Am I not doing the same in both, just at different places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a generator, use mid-stream variable binding to decompose your tuple within the for expression:

```
for (
  elem1 <- acc;
  (char, num) = elem; 
  i <- 0 to num
) yield ...
```

Comment: Ahh, so OP was trying to use the generator `<-` syntax on a non-collection (a single tuple) which is not the right tool for the job